# Why does `*this` resolve to the subclass?

Tags: c++, oop

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A;
class B;

void h(A &a) { std::cout << "a"; }
void h(B &b) { std::cout << "b"; }

class A {
    public:
    virtual void call() { h(*this); }
};

class B: public A {
    public:
    void call() override { h(*this); }
};

int main()
{
  B b = B{};
  A &test = b;
  
  h(test); // prints a
  test.call(); // prints b
}
```

I was messing around with code for a bit and noticed that `*this` always seemed to know which subclass it was, whereas normally we "lose information" when we initialize a subclass as a superclass object.

What exactly is going on behind the scenes to make `h(*this)` call `h(B &b)` instead of `h(A &a)`? What are the two calls in `main` doing differently such that one prints a, and the other prints b?

Comment: In `call` method, the method knows that the type of `*this` in the context.

Comment: Yes, that's evident from the program's behaviour, but I was more confused as to why this is the case.

Comment: Determine which function is being called at `test.call();`, `A::call` or `B::call`, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: A `virtual` method uses dynamic dispatch.  B overrides `call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h(test); // prints a
```

Since the type of `test` is `A &`, that's the overload that gets called. There's nothing more to say here. The End. The books are closed on this subject matter, and this is the compiler's job to do, here. The compiler figures out which overload to call based on what `test` is.

```
test.call();
```

This invokes `test`'s virtual method. Since `test` is actually `B`, this calls `B`'s overridden virtual method. That's how virtual methods work in C++.

Guess what happens in `B`?

```
void call() override { h(*this); }
```

Since the type of `*this` is `B &`, that's the overload that gets called. There's nothing more to say here. The End. The books are closed on this subject matter, and this is the compiler's job to do here. The compiler figures out which overload to call based on what `*this` is.